# mutex decorator in python

Tags: python, locking, coding-style, mutex, decorator

I saw this: http://yukelzon.blogspot.com/2005/07/python-locks.html when looking for a solution to add some locking to existing code around writing to a file.

The simplified version for my needs looks like this:

```
  def mlock(orig):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      Coloring.lock.acquire()
      try:
        ret = orig(*args, **kwargs)
        return ret
      finally:
        Coloring.lock.release()
    return inner
```

The lock is a class variable. Can any one think of improvements or better ways?

Comment: The scheme for accessing the lock, whether global or given, has no "right way", just different ways depending on needs. The answered version is identical in function to the semi-official version on the python wiki, which is also worth a look: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.6+ (I think), mutex objects are context managers, so:

```
def mlock(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        with Coloring.lock:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of free variables.  I would probably make the lock an explicit variable of the decorator, like so:

```
def mlock(Coloring):
    def mlock_decorator(orig):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
          Coloring.lock.acquire()
          try:
            ret = orig(*args, **kwargs)
            return ret
          finally:
            Coloring.lock.release()
        return inner
    return mlock_decorator
```

Well, since `Coloring` is a class variable, and if you expect this to be pretty specific to that class, access it explicitly:

```
def mlock(orig):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.Coloring.lock.acquire()
      try:
        ret = orig(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return ret
      finally:
        self.Coloring.lock.release()
    return inner
```

Or, at very least, declare that the lock is a global

```
def mlock(orig):
    global Coloring
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
      Coloring.lock.acquire()
      try:
        ret = orig(*args, **kwargs)
        return ret
      finally:
        Coloring.lock.release()
    return inner
```